# Why is this function increasing?

Tags: calculus, functions, cantor-set

$K$ : Cantor set

$\phi$ : $K \to [0,1]$, given by $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2\epsilon_k}{3^k} \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\epsilon_k}{2^k} \ (\epsilon_k=0,1)$

I hear that this function is increasing, but I don't understand why.

Probably, I have to see $x,y \in K, x<y \Rightarrow \phi(x)<\phi(y)$.

Why does this hold? I would like you to explain.

Comment: If $\epsilon(x)$ gives the ternary digits of $x$, so that  $\epsilon(x) = (\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \cdots)$ when $x = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2\epsilon_k}{3^k}$, then $x < y$ iff $\epsilon(x) < \epsilon(y)$ (lex order) because that's how you compare numbers given their digits.  And similarly if $\epsilon(x) < \epsilon(y)$ then $\phi(x) < \phi(y)$.